# Intuitions on perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I'm a QM newbie and I want to ask some questions on how to accept some peculiar points on this [perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29) thing naturally.
While they can be natural for most of the people, I find it somewhat hard to accept them. Can anybody help me understand these points with some nice intuitions?

1. 1st order energy correction can be calculated using only zeroth order wavefunctions
   This point can be quite natural, but if you see '2n+1 theorem' in perturbation theory...
2. '2n+1 theorem' states that by using only 1~nth order wavefunctions, you can calculate up to (2n+1)th order energy correction.
   I tried to understand this by gauge restrictions(I don't know if its right expression... what I mean is just counting the number of constraints like orthonormalization of zeroth order wf, orthogonality of zeroth and first order wf...)
   Actually, 1 is the special(and simpliest) case of 2.
3. What's more peculiar is this. Time dependent perturbation theory states that when you integrate nth order wavefunction correction, you can get (n+1)th order wavefunction correction.

Maybe peculiarity on 1,2,3 can be summed up as follows.
'You can get higher order corrections by some mathematical manipulations on lower order corrections'

Are these points just for perturbation theory? (e.g. natural consequence of mathematical structure of perturbation theory?)
Or some kind of spirit of approximation methods?

Comment: Tip: Consider adding references (to e.g. the '$2n+1$ theorem') in order to get useful and focused answers.

Comment: thank you very much!
http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.13120
this will do for 2n+1 theorem

Comment: there WAS a paper on the mathematical structure of perturbation theory and its extension 2n+1 theorem, but I had no permission to read it :<